# Google Cloud frequently doesn't have enough resources

Tags: google-compute-engine

> This is a [Canonical Question](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986) about a temporary shortage of available resources in Google Cloud services.

I'm a Brazilian user of Google Cloud's Compute Engine for a while and I managed to use it fine for quite some months. Unfortunately, in the last one month or so, I've been facing difficulties starting my instances (around 9 AM) due to the problem "the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request".

At the start, it happened once or twice and then I was able to start my instance. But now it's almost impossible to start it even after dozens of attempts! Following the message's suggestion, I tried to create other instances in `southamerica-east1-a` nd `c` (mine was in b) only to find out the same problem happening there. The impression I get from this is that Google has saturated their physical capacities in South America and are doing nothing to increase it.

So *what can I do about it?* I can't move my server to the USA or something because it's ping sensitive (stock market applications) and, as someone still using the free trial period, I certainly won't start paying for GC if Google may handle me a product I can't use and will take weeks or months to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to make sure that there are available resources in all zones.
Deploying and balancing your workload across multiple zones or regions to reduce the likelihood of an outage.

Please review our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps) which outlines how to build resilient and scalable architectures on Google Cloud Platform.