# Provisionning a GKE cluster stuck at Deploying step

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gcp

I am provisionning a simple GKE cluster thank to terraform with the more basic config and it is stuck at "Deploying"

"64% - Cluster is being deployed..."

And in my terminal

`google_container_cluster.katon_main_cluster: Still creating... [17m1s elapsed]`

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFAbM.png)

Is it something related to google at the moment ?

Thanks

Comment: Even `gcloud container clusters delete ...` does not seem to work in this situation: ```ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.delete) Some requests did not succeed:
 - ResponseError: code=400, message=Operation operation-1689024508732-ec64ed49-5561-41ef-90a3-6ff54ea75756 is currently creating cluster griffin-dev. Please wait and try again once it is done.``` - Confusing, that this seems to be a stuck-state in such a seemingly standard operation.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing today, ultimately got following error:

"The zone 'projects/<project_id>/zones/us-west4-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request."

For info on how to resolve the issue, see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016898/error-the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request).