# GCP doesn't have enough resources to complete the request

Tags: google-compute-engine

I had to restart my ubuntu 16.04 server in the zone asia-south so I hit the stop and as i tried starting it again, it throws an error of "asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later." My main problem is I have my applications installed in the server and the server is in terminated state. Is there any way i can restart my server or move the instance to another nearby zone without loosing my application data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud frequently doesn't have enough resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/938972/google-cloud-frequently-doesnt-have-enough-resources)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a snapshot and make a new instances in another place and while creating it use the snapshot and if you can please tell me your server config it can also be due to the amount of vcore and memory

Answer (score 0):

From your description seems like you terminated the machine. Anyway, it might worth a try using the [move](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#top_of_page) feature to relocate your instance without having to go through the snapshot process.

First determine the state of the machine:

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe --zone your_zone instance_name --flatten="status"
```

If you don't get `TERMINATED`, then you can issue this:

```
$ gcloud compute instances move instance-1 --zone zone-a --destination-zone zone-b
```

If this is not the case and your instance cannot be moved, then try the [snapshot approach](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).

Basically you'll need to locate the disk associated with your instance, protect it from deletion, make a snapshot and use that snapshot to create another disk in a different zone.

You might want to check the zone status before going through this:

```
$ gcloud compute zones describe zone_name
```

After that, you can run these commands (replacing the env vars with your data):

```
gcloud compute instances set-disk-auto-delete ${INSTANCE_NAME} --zone ${ORIGINAL_ZONE} --disk ${DISK_NAME} --no-auto-delete
gcloud compute disks snapshot ${DISK_NAME} --snapshot-names ${SNAPSHOT_NAME} --zone ${ORIGINAL_ZONE}
gcloud compute instances delete ${INSTANCE_NAME} --zone ${ORIGINAL_ZONE} //This might be optional at this point
gcloud compute disks snapshot ${DISK_NAME} --snapshot-names {SNAPSHOT_NAME} --zone ${ORIGINAL_ZONE}
gcloud compute disks create ${NEW_DISK_NAME} --source-snapshot ${SNAPSHOT_NAME} --zone ${NEW_ZONE}
gcloud compute instances create ${NEW_INSTANCE} --machine-type n1-standard-1 --zone ${NEW_ZONE} --disk name=${NEW_DISK},boot=yes,mode=rw
```

For the whole detailed process, [check here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).

It's worth noting that this happens whenever resource demand in a certain zone is too high at any given time. This means that eventually, resources will be available and you'll be able to turn on your machine.

GCP [recomends building highly available systems](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps#design_for_high_availability) to avoid this kind of situations.