# Is Google Cloud Mumbai - Asia-south1-a/b/c facing issues due to COVID ? Unable to Create or Start an instance since 1 month

Tags: google-compute-engine

Hi Is Google Cloud Mumbai (Asia-South1) facing issues due to COVID situation in Mumbai ? I am unable to create a new Compute Instance or start my old instance in all of the zones in Asia-South1 Mumbai region for over a month now in Zone A,B or C. I keep getting "Not Enough Resources available in this Zone".

I am trying to create a 8GB RAM - 4 VCPU on E2 Platform instance with Cent OS 7 & 20GB SSD Disk space.

I have waited for almost one month now and still no resolution of this issue. If this doesn't resolve soon it will cause a huge problem for my company from our clients. Kindly help please !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud frequently doesn't have enough resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/938972/google-cloud-frequently-doesnt-have-enough-resources)

Answer (score 0):

You can check current status of GCP services at [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/):

> This page provides status information on the services that are part of
> Google Cloud Platform. Check back here to view the current status of
> the services listed below.

Let's have a look at **the cause of the error message you've got**: when you create and start VM instance it requests resources like vCPU and memory and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message like this:

```
    The zone 'projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/ZONE_NAME' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

more information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

> If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
> or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
> resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
> request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
> and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

**The  reason for this behavior** is resource availability which depends from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve it**:

1. Try to create VM instance at [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection).
2. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM instances by following documentation to avoid such issue in future:

> Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
> zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
> additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
> your workloads when you need them. *After you create a reservation, you
> begin paying for the reserved resources immediately*, and they remain
> available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
> is deleted.

3. Wait for a while and try again.

If nothing helped, you can try to contact with [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

Answer (score 0):

this issue happens only if you have trail account.
if you switch to paid account and run VMs , it will allow you to do so. most likely sales and marketing strategy.