# GCP - Compute - Cannot start VM, the zone does not have enough resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The question has been asked several times, the error is

> The zone 'projects/xxx/zones/yyy' does not have enough resources
> available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again
> later.

The best solution is migrate to another zone.

But! If the machine has a licensed sw, enabled right for that instance (as for many windows licenced softwares) you cannot really move to another zone as you will have a clone with a different HW signature and the application won't start: quite frustrating, what's the best advice, in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud frequently doesn't have enough resources](https://serverfault.com/questions/938972/google-cloud-frequently-doesnt-have-enough-resources)

Comment: Not really, Michael. My question is about, for example, how to restart a windows instance after resizing memory: moving to a different zone is not a solution, that resource trouble stops operations for hours, if not days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you [stop an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) it releases some resources like vCPU and memory.
2. When you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) (or change it) it requests resources like vCPU and memory back and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message:

   ```
   Error: Starting VM instance "INSTANCE_NAME" failed. Error: The zone 'projects/XXXX/zones/ZONE' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
   ```

more information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

> If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
> or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
> resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
> request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
> and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

3. Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve such issue** without moving it to another zone:

1. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again.
2. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future (*extra payment required*):

> Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
> zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
> additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
> your workloads when you need them. After you create a reservation, you
> begin paying for the reserved resources immediately, and they remain
> available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
> is deleted.

Comment: Do you know how long it usually takes to resolve this problem? A zone I have resources in has been unable to start a VM for an entire week now.. :(

Comment: Unfortunately such events hard to predict and there's no information about resolution time.